# How do I use variables from config.ini.php?

Tags: 8

I have a **config.ini.php** file as follows :

```
;<?php
;die(); // For further security
; // These php lines are used to hide the data from the browser
; // They are both valid php and valid ini files
;/*
; Don't forget to disable and reenable module, after adjusting the values
[folders]
var_1= "value1"
var_2 = "value2"
```

And in **module_name.install** file, I am using it as follows.

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_enable().
 */
function module_name_enable() {
  $config_file = 'config.ini.php';
  $parameters = parse_ini_file($config_file);
  foreach ($parameters as $key => $value) {
    \Drupal::state()->set($key, $value);
    \Drupal::config('module_name.settings')
      ->set($key, $value)
      ->save();
  }
}
```

I then try to use a variable with the following code.

```
$getvar = \Drupal::config('module_name.settings')
      ->get('var_1'); 
\Drupal::state()->get('var_1', '');
```

I am not getting the value. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, you shouldn't be using a "config.ini.php" file for configs in your custom module.

You should have a /examplemodule/config/install/examplemodule.settings.yml file like this:

```
var_1: "value1"
var_2: "value2"
```

Then when you reinstall your module, it adds the values.  There's no need to run code in hook_install.

To access the values, use:

```
\Drupal::config('examplemodule.settings')->get('var_1');
```

and to edit:

```
\Drupal::configFactory()
  ->getEditable('examplemodule.settings')
  ->set('var_1', $value)
  ->save();
```

You're using state correctly, I tested this out:

```
\Drupal::state()->set('var_1', $value);

$var_1 = \Drupal::state()->get('var_1');
```

Comment: thanks for your insight , i was wrongly given hook_enable instead of hook_install and done by the usual way of  setting in install file **\Drupal::state()->set('var_1', $value);**
and used in module file as **$var_1 = \Drupal::state()->get('var_1');**

Comment: Your solutions works too ,and  I think its the drupal 8 way of doing it :)

Answer (score 3):

`hook_enable` doesn't exist any more. Your code should be in [`hook_install`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_install/8.2.x)

Other than that, this will set a value:

```
\Drupal::configFactory()
  ->getEditable('module_name.settings')
  ->set('var_1', $value)
  ->save();
```

And this will retrieve it:

```
\Drupal::config('module_name.settings')
  ->get('var_1');
```

Just tried it, confirmed to be working. If you're still not seeing the value, there's something wrong with your non-Drupal code (the ini file parsing), or the context in which you're trying to retrieve it.

Comment: btw i have no settings file in the module , and it through me error like : **Drupal\Core\Config\ImmutableConfigException: Can not set values on immutable configuration module_name.settings:var_1. Use \Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface::getEditable() to retrieve a mutable configuration object in Drupal\Core\Config\ImmutableConfig->set() (line 32 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/ImmutableConfig.php).**

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have a new problem...

Comment: Actually don't, that's the same problem isn't it! I was trying this against an old version of D8, give me a minute and I'll update with the proper code

Comment: Could you please explain how to get/set array variables in the same file?