# How to retrieve ConfigEntity instance from config factory?

Tags: 8, entities

I have defined a config entity in my module (schema and class that extends `ConfigEntityBase`) - `MyConfigEntity`.

When I use config factory to get config, Drupal returns instance of `Config` or `ImmutableConfig`. How can I retrieve instance of `MyConfigEntity` instead?

```
$config = \Drupal::config('my_module.config.something');
// Now $config is instance of ImmutableConfig.
```

Comment: this is a duplicate:  see
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/203371/how-do-i-use-variables-from-config-ini-php/203394#203394

Comment: @oknate No it's not. My question is specifically about config entities.

Comment: OK, I stand corrected.  I didn't know there was a config entity vs. a config.  What are config entities used for?

Comment: Ah, after poking a round, the big advantage for config entities is they are stored in yml and can be exported, where other entities, such as nodes, cannot be.

Comment: @oknate for example node type is a config entity. Same as taxonomy vocabulary. You also get CRUD and you can basically handle them like any other entity, for example you can reference them in other entities (that's what node does)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[\Drupal::config()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3Aconfig/8.2.x)

> Retrieves a configuration object.
>
> This is the main entry point to the configuration API.

The configuration API is a different system than the entity API.

```
$entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('my_config_entity')
  ->load($id);
```

Configuration entity types should be used to store configurable content like content types or other site builder-esque things that you want to deploy from environment to environment that is not managed content (Something a content author would write).

If you're looking for a complex configuration object, then you should define that in `config/mymodule.settings.yml` and use the configuration API like in your question.

Comment: Damn, that's yet another dependency.

Answer (score 6):

Check this out [configFactory](https://www.drupal.org/node/2407153).

You just need to do:

`\Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('my_module.config.something');`